# Scale raster cell in stack from -1 to 1 with R

Tags: raster, scale

I have a raster stack with 364 layers with a daily rate of change in NDVI values.

I want to scale these values in every cell if positive from 0 to 1 and if negative from -1 to 0. So far I have only found solutions that scale values in single layers and not along cells of multilayer objects.

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to scale each band to its min/max or the min/max of *all* the bands? What software are you using? Is this to be done in a script/program or are you trying to do it with tools?

Comment: `newval = (curval / maxval) if (curval >= 0) else (-curval / minval)`

Comment: @Micheal Stimson: Thanks! Sorry, should have mentioned it, I work with R, hence I would do it with a script. I want to scale the values to min/max of all band but in every cell separately (so kind of a local min/max but for the entire time series).